# Relationship between the conductor of an extension $L/K$ and that of the Dirichlet's character on $Gal(L/K)$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, galois-extensions

Let $d$ be an odd prime and $d \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. For quadratic extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q}$, the only prime that is ramified is $d$, and it is also the conductor of the extension. So the conductor of the extension is same as the conductor defined on the Dirichlet characters. How do I prove this?

Also, if I have $\mathbb{Q}(d^{1/p})/\mathbb{Q}$ where $p$ is some odd prime, how do I find the conductors? I am trying to use the discriminant-conductor formula for cubic extensions to try and estimate what conductors are using the discriminant but I am unable to make any progress. So how do I show this?

Since the extension $(L=\mathbb{Q}(d^{1/p}))/{K}$, (where $K$ contains the $p$-th roots of unity) is abelian so $\chi(1)=1$ but what are the values of the conductors? My understanding says that for $p=3$ there will be three Artin conductors defined at $1, \omega, \omega^2$ but what is their value? I know that only primes ramified in the extension $L/K$ in this case of $p=3$ are $(1-omega), d$ but then how is the conductor $3d$?

So how are these conductors related to the conductor of the extension and the ramified primes?

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: The first sentence is nonsense. So is the second.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I am sorry I just noticed, I edited it.

Comment: What is the conductor for a non-abelian extension ?

Comment: @reuns I do not really know anything about Class Field Theory, I am sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: A Dirichlet character $\chi \bmod m$ is a homomorphism on $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times$, which can be interpreted as ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)/\mathbf Q)$. We can associate to $\chi$ its kernel in that Galois group, and by Galois theory that kernel has a fixed field $F$ inside $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$. The field $F$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbf Q$ and it might lie inside several  cyclotomic fields $\mathbf Q(\zeta_d)$ where $d \leq m$. The conductor of $\chi$ turns out to be the least such $d$.  Conductors of abelian extensions $L/K$ generalize this point of view: study CFT to see it.

Comment: 1. Look at the case $d = 15$ to see what's wrong with your first sentence. 2. It is not the brightest idea to start learning class field theory with Artin conductors.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer $d$ is an odd prime here, sorry for the notation.

Comment: Then have a look at $d = 3$.

Comment: Oh right, because $2$ will also be ramified here. I see. Thanks a lot professor @franzlemmermeyer!